# detect fingers in hand

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, contour

I have a image

[image]

this image is output of threshold function. 
I want to detect the specified object as above and measure their heights.
My idea is extracting contours and use convex hull but my result not correct.

Have anyone idea for this problem?
regards.
Sys : Win7(64bit),OpenCV 3.1,Visual Studio 2015

my output :

[image]

here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void*);

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
/// Load source image and convert it to gray
src = imread("C:/Users/Amin/Desktop/binary.jpg", 1);

/// Convert image to gray and blur it
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

/// Create Window
char* source_window = "Source";
namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow(source_window, src);

createTrackbar(" Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh,      thresh_callback);
thresh_callback(0, 0);

waitKey(0);
return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{
Mat src_copy = src.clone();
Mat threshold_output;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

/// Detect edges using Threshold
threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

/// Find contours
findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

/// Find the convex hull object for each contour
vector<vector<Point> >hull(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
}

/// Draw contours + hull results
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
    drawContours(drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
}

/// Show in a window
namedWindow("Hull demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Hull demo", drawing);
 }
```

I achieved this result but don't know how to measure AB?
A is on the contour and B is known.

[image]
thanks

Comment: Can you provide us with the input image `C:/Users/Amin/Desktop/binary.jpg` ? The one you have put in your post is polluted with the markings so it's difficult for me to test it..

Comment: Here is the test image: http://uupload.ir/files/yqn0_6.jpg

Comment: Is the camera fix mounted ? If so, the fingers can just move up and down am i right?

Comment: @PSchn: you are aright. this is one frame of video in witch the fingers move up and down and camera is fixed.

Comment: can you post an image from the fingers when there are moved up? and what about the background? Is it changing ?

Comment: here is the movie :https://www.dropbox.com/s/23wgmxr6wdcxnac/tt.rar?dl=0

Comment: in this movie, background do not change.

Answer (score 0):

To measure heights (I think thats what you are asking?) there is little point in using Convex hull - **considering** this messy output. Instead, I would loop through each contour (1,2,3,4 and 5) and all their points, and detect the widths and heights separately by analysing the X,Y differences. so, while you loop through lets say contour 1, if Y is increasing but not X, you can assume it is the height .. so count each point. Then, when X starts to increase, assume the height has come to an end. You will want to set a tolerance as the lines are not perfectly straight. Hope this helps.